# Sliding animation when clicking on link that navigates to other part of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think the title says enough. So have now is that when I click on "Example 4" it scrolls the page to the h1 of Example 4. But it is so ugly that when I click on it, it just BOOM is there. I want it to scroll smoothly, can this be done with only html/css or do I need jQuery/JS or something? This is a quick example from what I have right now.

```
<html>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.----.com/#ex1">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.----.com/#ex2">Example 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.----.com/#ex3">Example 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.----.com/#ex4">Example 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.----.com/#ex5">Example 5</a></li>
    </ul>


    <h1 id="ex1">Example 1</h1>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
        sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        <br />

    <h1 id="ex2">Example 2</h1>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
        sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        <br />

    <h1 id="ex3">Example 3</h1>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
        sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        <br />

    <h1 id="ex4">Example 4</h1>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
        sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        <br />

    <h1 id="ex5">Example 5</h1>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
        sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        <br />

</body>
```

**EDIT:** [*Here*](http://design.grafisch-centrumshop.nl/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=5)'s a link to my website by the way ;3.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your href links like this..it should work

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="#ex1">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ex2">Example 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ex3">Example 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ex4">Example 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ex5">Example 5</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: No man, doesn't work for me. But I just thought about that I can just put the link to my website on here. "Artikel 10" is done the way you told me. I'll add the link to my site into my question.

Comment: Check out this link : http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_locations

Comment: Hmmm, it works for you I see.. But what you have, I do also but the thing I want to change is that when you click on one of them you get a smooth scrolling to that title.

Comment: You can add this in your css to make the transition in a smooth fashion :
div {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

Comment: I allready fixed it myself watching some tutorials about jQuery. If you post it as an answer I'll choose you as best answer ;).